# Is it possible to use the 7zip standalone file (7za.exe) for data archival without changing the path variable?

Tags: batch-file, archive, 7zip

I tested a batch script for data archival in my local machine by changing the path variable to refer to the 7zip package's location.

I used the following code for performing the archival.

```
7za a -tzip \\tm1data-studio-dev\wds\WDS_DISTRIBUTION_01\TM1\USER_FILES\Target\Archival_%DD%_%MM%_%YYYY%_%HH%_%MN%.zip \\tm1data-studio-dev\wds\WDS_DISTRIBUTION_01\TM1\USER_FILES\Intermediate\
```

Is there a way I can use 7za.exe without changing the path variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the 7za is in the same directory as the script / console current directory. Though changing path in the script will affect only the current cmd session.What's the problem to use `SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\something`  ?

Comment: The 7za.exe file and the batch script are both present in the same location. :( Could it be that the 7zip command isn't working because of the shared environment?

Comment: It might be that `7za.exe` needs some DLLs or similar from its home directory (I haven't got it on my current machine to check).  Either include them in the current directory or, if you don't want to permanently modify `PATH`, you can use `setlocal` before doing so, so the changes only apply within the batch file.

Comment: What is the result if you use `7za.exe` without changing the path? Is there any message that appears? Also, what does "shared environment" mean?

Answer (score 1):

`7za.exe` is the stand-alone version of *7-Zip* which does not need any additional DLL.

I suggest using the following command line in the batch file with `7za.exe` being stored always in same directory as the batch file:

```
"%~dp07za.exe" a -tzip "\\tm1data-studio-dev\wds\WDS_DISTRIBUTION_01\TM1\USER_FILES\Target\Archival_%DD%_%MM%_%YYYY%_%HH%_%MN%.zip" "\\tm1data-studio-dev\wds\WDS_DISTRIBUTION_01\TM1\USER_FILES\Intermediate"
```

`%~dp0` is replaced by the Windows command processor on execution of the batch file by drive and path of the batch file ending with a backslash. The help of command **CALL** output by running in a command prompt window `call /?`  explains `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 which is the full batch file path). This is useful if the current working directory on execution of the batch file is different to directory of the batch file and `7za.exe`.

It can be seen what `cmd.exe` does on processing the batch file by running the batch file from within a command prompt window with the first line modified from `@echo off` to `@echo on` if this line is used in the batch file at all.

Further each modification on environment variables within a batch file is visible only for the batch file and all applications started from within this batch file. Windows creates on execution of a batch file a **copy** of entire environment variables list for the command process. Therefore modifying **PATH** as suggested by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) is absolutely safe as just the local copy of **PATH** is modified and not system environment variable **PATH**.

Comment: Woo hoo!! That did the trick mate! :D It was indeed an issue with the current working directory being different than the location of the batch file and the standalone console. Thanks a lot!